# ¿Es posible acotar una gráfica de python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, gráficas

Hice un programa que grafica muros con ladrillos y necesito acotar la gráfica a necesidad, como cuando se acota una medida en AutoCAD por ejemplo. ¿Es esto posible? He buscado mucho en internet pero no encuentro respuesta. De no ser posible, que otra opción me podrían recomendar para tener mi gráfica, poder acotarla y finalmente imprimirla.

Adjunto una imagen del muro con la cota que me gustaría poder hacer.

Gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Posiblemente con `xlim()` y `ylim()` pero sin código no se puede dar una solución exacta.

Comment: Primero, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. La verdad estoy aprendiendo a programar y por necesidad empecé con python. Sabes de algún otro programa para visualizar datos en donde si pueda acotar? Porque hacerlo solo con código para cada muro que haga me tomaría mucho tiempo

Comment: Ese es un mundo que desconozco, lamentablemente :(